# Java - How to close SQLite Connection throwing exceptions?

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I've seen many examples of closing database connections where people use `finally{}` in the DAO method, but in my case the DAO method (ex: insertUsers()) throws its exceptions to the method it's called. In this case, how can i close my connections?

I'm getting the "SQLiteException - Database is locked" error.

Here's my code:

**DAO**

```
public static Connection con = null;
private static boolean hasData = false;

private void getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:ProjFarmacia.db");
    initialise();
}

private void initialise() throws SQLException {
   if( !hasData ){
       hasData = true;
       Statement state = con.createStatement();
       ResultSet res = state.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='caixa'");
       if(!res.next()){
           Statement state2 = con.createStatement();
           state2.execute("CREATE TABLE caixa(id integer, timestamp integer, valorTotal double,  notas1 integer, notas2 integer,"
                   + " notas5 integer, notas10 integer, notas20 integer"
                   + "notas50 integer, notas100 integer, moedas1 integer, moedas5 integer, moedas10 integer, moedas25 integer"
                   + "moedas50 integer, moedas1R integer, primary key(id));");
       }   
   }
}




public ResultSet getCaixaByDate(long timestamp) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    if(con == null){
        getConnection();
    }

    Statement state = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet res = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM caixa WHERE timestamp=" + "'" + timestamp + "'" + ";");
    return res;
}


public void createCaixa(Caixa caixa) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    if(con == null){
        getConnection();
    }
    PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO caixa VALUES(?,?);");
    prep.setLong(1, caixa.getTimestamp());
    prep.setDouble(2, caixa.getValorTotal());
    con.close();
}
```

**MAIN APPLICATION**

```
  try {
        ResultSet rs = caixaDAO.getCaixaByDate(timestamp);

        //If not exists in database
        if(!rs.next()){
            Caixa caixa = new Caixa();
            caixa.setTimestamp(timestamp);
            caixa.setValorTotal(venda.getValorDaVenda());

            //Inserting new Caixa
            caixaDAO.createCaixa(caixa);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Caixa already created!!!");
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(VendaMedicamento.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
```

Comment: What prevents you from using `finally`? And are you really running this on Android?

Comment: The connection is not available outside the DAO.... and i'm running on my PC first so i can pass it to Android